# GoogleCalendarAPI Unregistered on API console

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I have facing below error while integrating Google Calendar.

Please check my below code.

Thanks in advance.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
                                                                        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:286)
                                                                        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
                                                                        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
                                                                        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
                                                                        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
                                                                        at com.taskdemocal.AsyncLoadTasks.doInBackground(AsyncLoadTasks.java:38)
                                                                        at com.taskdemocal.CommonAsyncTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyncTask.java:55)
                                                                        at com.taskdemocal.CommonAsyncTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyncTask.java:33)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
```