# GoogleAuthException: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE when trying to use Google Sheets API V4

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

I have registered my app on the API Console
[image: API Console]

You can see here that the SHA 1 key matches
[image: SHA 1 key from console]

And the package name from the manifest matches as well
[image: manifest]

App signing is configured
[image: app signing]

And is in use by the debug build
[image]

And the sheets API is enabled
[image]

And yet every time my code tries to interact with a sheet I get an Exception

```
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
```

I have done much googling on this, and found many people with the same issue, but the solution for them was to register their debug fingerprint on the API console, which I have done.

I have also generated a separate keystore and key for production, registered that on the API console and then built a signed APK but to no avail.

I have been trying to figure this out for days, I keep coming back to it and not making any headway. What am I missing?

Comment: How you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

You may also check if the error was caused by misspell in package name in [AndroidManifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41075867/5832311).

Additional reference:

- [GoogleCalendarAPI Unregistered on API console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395505/googlecalendarapi-unregistered-on-api-console)

  > Ensure that you have annotated your Cloud Endpoints API correctly with the clientIds and audiences. The Android Audience value is the same as that of the Web Client Id. Make sure you have deployed the updated API and regenerated the Endpoints API sources for inclusion in your Android application.

Comment: No typo, I had copypasted it over